# How to get BASHPID in Bash version 3

Tags: bash, macos

On MacOS we have bash version 3.2 installed by default.
Is there a way to get BASHPID for subshell or is it just impossible?

For what I gather online this is the case:

```
current_pid="$$"

(
  [[ "$current_pid" != "$$" ]] && exit 1
  [[ "$BASHPID" == "$$" ]] && exit 1
)
```

so the BASHPID is the same unless you're in a subshell. So with Bash version 3 is there a way to get the PID of the subshell?

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: You have numerous questions with no accepted answers. If you keep leaving answers given to your questions unaccepted, nobody will answer your questions to come.

Comment: I always upvote, I don't always accept unless I completely verify the answer

Comment: Okay, but you should let the answerers know what is wrong with their answers, you should give them feedbacks.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674793/212680

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BASHPID was introduced in bash-4.0-alpha](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES), so I would expect no.